# Why do I keep getting a null reference to my LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout called `view.xml` which contains a `View` called `view_related`. Basically, in my dictionary app, if there are related words to an entry, I will replace `view_related` with a `LinearLayout` that contains a header "Related entries" and a bunch of `TextView`s representing every related word.

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` everytime I'm adding a `TextView` to the `LinearLayout` in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, and I don't understand why though my code looks pretty straightforward.

view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/view_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#990011"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="lalala word"
        />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/view_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/view_header">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view_description_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/demo_definition"
                />
                <!-- THIS WILL BE REPLACED -->
            <View android:id="@+id/view_related"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_related.xml, the `LinearLayout` that will replace the `View` element in view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_related_entries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/view_related_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:background="#000"
        android:text="Related entries"
        />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view_related_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the `onCreate` method, which for now assumes the related entries are "Hello" and "Goodbye:"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_related_list);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello");
    ll.addView(tv); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Goodbye");
    ll.addView(tv);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.view_related);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(view);
    parent.removeView(view);
    View llview = li.inflate(R.id.view_related_entries, parent, false);
    parent.addView(llview, index);
}
```

Comment: You need to search for the `LinearLayout` after you inflate the layout. Also regarding your current situation you should use a `ViewStub` instead of that `View` that you remove to substitute with the inflated layout.

Comment: check your code line by line using log and and see at which line you are getting exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line (`LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_related_list);`) will search for `view_related_list` in `view.xml`, as in the line before that is the view you are using..

You need to inflate `view_related.xml` first and then get the view from it..

Answer (score 2):

```
setContentView(R.layout.view);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_related_list);
```

The function `findViewById` only finds views that are actually set. Your current `setContentView` does not set an xml that has the id you are looking for in it, so the first line I quoted will not result in anything.

You should either load the correct XML, or inflate the view you are looking for with an inflater

Comment: Gee, I didn't know that. This really explains the error I got.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of wrong things in your code. First you search for a `LinearLayout` that isn't in the current layout and also isn't in any inflated layout at that moment. Second, you try to inflate an `id` reference instead of a `layout` reference. Last, you should use another approach for what you're trying to do. Your code should be(from what I understood):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);   

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.view_related);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(view);
    parent.removeView(view);
    View llview = li.inflate(R.layout.view_related, parent, false); // is view_related the name of the extra layout file?
    parent.addView(llview, index);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_related_list); // or search for it in llview, llview.findViewById(R.id.view_related_list);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello");
    ll.addView(tv); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Goodbye");
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

This is a situation when you should use a [`ViewStub`](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html) to add the new layout file. Although, I don't understand why don't you add the new layout file directly in the `view.xml` if you're going to add the layout's content in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Haven't used `ViewStub`s before, definitely checking that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use `setContentView(R.layout.view_related);` instead of `setContentView(R.layout.view);`

or another simple thing you can do is take the linear layout in the same layout "view" and make it invisible when not required and visible when required

Comment: Hmm, maybe not exactly. `R.layout.view` contains the word and the definition. `R.layout.view_related` is the entire view for the "related entries" part, which will not be inflated if there aren't any.

Comment: yes yes you are right. What about the concept of inflating to the view (like to a listview. I am not sure but if you can give it a try)?

Answer (score -1):

You may forgetting to declare your Activity in manifest.xml

Comment: then tell me on which line you are getting Null pointer exception, I will fix

Comment: got it, ll.addView(tv); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
let me check again

Comment: tv.setId(int);//int any int value
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.addview(tv);
this should work